# wolfmqtt connect command with freertos+tcp

Tags: mqtt, freertos

I am trying to make an MQTT client on SAMV71 with freeRTOS+TCP. After TCP handshake the client is supposed to send MQTT to connect command and broker respond by connecting ACK.

The broker sends TCP window update but the window is still 1000. Can it be something wrong with the buffer size to not match the calculated window size? The client is sending TCP retransmission instead of connecting command.[This picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOxkj.png) shows the packets between broker and client. The retransmission packet contains the payload that the connect command should.